# How to create border that has the heading on the same level as the border line?

Tags: html, css, border

Kind of a confusing request to phrase. But basically I'd like to have a border around content that has some text centered on the top middle of the border, without having the border strike through the text. Please see the attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkDtL.png). Also, I will edit to provide my code if you deem it necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:
https://jsfiddle.net/4nhk3ooy/1/

You put your header inside the box and then put it `position:absolute` with correct offset. Then you set the background of header to correct color. Also put some padding to it, so there is some space between border and text. Then you just have to correctly count the offset. Also take in mind, that for some responsive features, you might want to write some JS algorithm to count everything depending on size of screen (because you will have to handle text size, after that alter header width, after that alter header padding and after that take all this and calculate correct offset)

And also take note, that the bordered box has to be also positioned, relative, absolute or fixed, or your absolutely positioned header will not be positioned against the div, but against the screen.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very helpful.